# jQuery if height

Tags: jquery, if-statement, each

I have couple of divs with class "priceText" and I am trying to accomplish that if div.priceText height is smaller than 100px, than hide image in **this** div.

I cant get this to work. I have managed to hide **all** images on **all** .priceText divs IF height in one of the .priceText divs is smaller than 100px, but I need just to hide that image witch is in this div witch is smaller than 100px.

So my unfinished code :

```
$(".priceText").each(function() {

var $minHeight = 100;
var $priceHeight = $('.priceText').height();

if ( $priceHeight < $minHeight) {
$("img", this).remove();
}

});
```

Comment: Why do you prefix your vars with a `$`? Don't do that. Especially don't use the `$` prefix for vars that do not contain jQuery objects!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do:

```
$(".priceText").each(function() {

var $minHeight = 100;
//you need the height of the div you are currently iterating on: use this
if ( $(this).height() < $minHeight) {
//find the img in this div and hide it
$(this).find('img').remove();
}

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `var $priceHeight = $('.priceText').height();` to `var $priceHeight = $(this).height();`

The way you have it, it is trying to get the height on all elements with a class of priceText, not the one you're currently referencing.

Comment: This is correct, but $("img", this).remove(); removes both the div and all the images!

Comment: Not true, Nicola. `this` is context. See here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1